# Can't connect to MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following a guide from a book and all the code looks fine, but I can't connect to my database. It's pretty annoying, I've got all privileges granted and what not. The connect file is set on for sure.

Everything works up to the connection phase but I'm completely miffed, tried everyone, tried creating a new user and all that jazz. Nothing appears to be wrong with the code. I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Is something a-miss?

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'sam');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'whatever');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'beginner');

$dbcon = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL:' .mysql_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset($dbcon, 'utf8'); ?>
```

That's my external, but here's the initiating code:

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors = array();
    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You did not enter a first name.';
    }
else { $fn = trim($_POST['fname']);
    }
if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You did not enter a last name.';
    }
else { $ln = trim($_POST['lname']);
    }

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You did not enter your e-mail address.';
    }
else {$e = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['psword1'])) {
    if ($_POST['psword1'] !=$_POST['psword2']) {
    $errors[] = 'Your passwords were not the same';
    }
else {$p = trim($_POST['psword1']);
    }
    }
    else { $errors[] = 'You did not enter your password.';
    }

if (empty($errors)) {
    require ('mysql_connect.php');

    $q = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, fname, lname, email, psword, registration_date)
    VALUES (' ', '$fn', '$ln', '$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW() )";
    $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);
    if ($result) {
    header ('location: ../register-thanks.php');
    exit();
    }

    else {echo '<h2>Error!</h2>
    <p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologise for any inconvenience.</p>';
    echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($dbcon); '<br><br>Query:'.$q.'</p>';}

    include ('footer.php');
    exit();
    }

    else {
        echo '<h2>Error!</h2>
        <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo " - $msg<br>\n";
            }
            echo '</p><h3>Please try again</h3><p><br></p>';
            }
            }
            ?>
```

It requires a re-direct. don't feel it's necessary but here it is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<title>Registration thank you page</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
<?php include ("nav.php"); ?>
<?php include ("info-col.php"); ?>
<div id="content">
<p>The thank you page content. The thank you page content. The thank you page content.<br> 
The thank you page.The thank you page content. The thank you page content.<br>The thank  
you page content. The thank you page. 
The thank you page content.<br>The thank you page  content. The thank you page content. The thank you page content</p>
</div>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error does it throw? have you tried localhost instead of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Remove the @ - you're suppressing errors with it.

Comment: I've done it but it's still just returning the default else error statement, nothing specific at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the '@' sign, as user [Jimbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736809/jimbo) says in his comment. That should stop suppressing errors. After that, enable PHP's error reporting.

Example:

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

define( 'DB_USER', 'sam' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'whatever' );
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'beginner' );

$dbcon = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME )
    OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL:' . mysql_connect_error() );
mysqli_set_charset( $dbcon, 'utf8' );
```

Comment: Sorry guys, still getting nothing! Real pain in the you know what.

Comment: Okay, so I sat the connect in the folder above as specified in the guide but forgot to point to the folder above, the errors are showing. Thank you for your help. Wonderful people.

Comment: Happy to help! Consider closing your post or accepting an answer.